# change default character set of PHP functions like "htmlspecialchars"

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am using PHP 5.2.6 and my app's character set is UTF-8.

Now, how should I change PHP's default character set? 
NOT the one which specifies output's mime time and character set.

But which will change for all the PHP function like htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, etc.

I know, there is a parameter in those functions which takes the character set of the input string. But I don't want to specify for all the functions I use. And if somewhere I forget, it will be mess.

I also know, that I can wrap those functions and create my own wrapper like:

```
function myHtmlize($str)
{
  return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
```

I also, don't like this solution.

I really want to tell PHP, that by default take 'UTF-8' as the character set. Not 'iso-8859-1'.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible but this is a good question. +1

Answer (score 2):

Like this one ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

```
* LC_ALL for all of the below
* LC_COLLATE for string comparison, see strcoll()
* LC_CTYPE for character classification and conversion, for example strtoupper()
* LC_MONETARY for localeconv()
* LC_NUMERIC for decimal separator (See also localeconv())
* LC_TIME for date and time formatting with strftime()
* LC_MESSAGES for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a C-function *determine_charset(char *charset_hint ...)* which is used to find the "right" charset based on

- what has been passed as *charset_hint*
- the setting of [mb_internal_encoding](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding)
- [default_charset](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset)
- compile-time CODESET
- last but not least: [LC_CTYPE locale](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

in that order and depending on whether some extensions are built-in or not.
The "problem" is, when you call *htmlentities('xyz')* this *determine_charset()* is called with charset_hint=NULL and the first this function does is:

```
/* Guarantee default behaviour for backwards compatibility */
if (charset_hint == NULL)
    return cs_8859_1;
```

You have to call at least htmlentities('xyz', ENT_QUOTES, **''**)

Comment: That's what exactly I want to get rid of.

Comment: I don't see how, unless you change php's source code (most likely for the htmlentities function)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I *think* `mbstring.func_overload` works with `htmlentities.`

`htmlspecialchars` is charset-neutral btw. (At least as long as the charset supports the ascii subset, which utf-8 does).

Comment: This isn't quite correct, anything outside the ascii/win-1252 range will be mauled by htmlentities if you don't specify character set.

Answer (score 0):

From php.net:

> 5.4.0     The default value for the encoding parameter was changed to UTF-8.

In modern times you need just update your version of PHP to 5.4 or better and set the default_charset directive in php.ini to UTF-8 (which is already the default). You may also be able to do it programatially like this:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Sources:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php